# How to make Typescript HTTP decorators please?

Tags: node.js, typescript, decorator

I'm making a REST api in Nodejs, Express, Typescript, PostgreSQL.

I never made any Typescript decorators. I'm trying to learn it right now and I need your help.

I would like to make decorators like we can find in Nestjs : "@Get() @Post() @Delete() @Put() @Patch() @Controller() @Params() @Body()" but I cannot find any tutorial on how to make them :(

I do not want to use an existing package. I really want to learn and make it myself.

How do we write them and how my Express server will create the corresponding router and routes ?

Like this :

```
@Get("/:id")
findOneHandler(@Params() id: string){
...
}}
```

Thank in advance for your help !

Comment: You can read about Typescript decorators here: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html

Comment: Out of curiosity why not use nestjs? By default it uses express.

Comment: Express does not know anything about the decorators. Other packages provide them. One of them is [`routing-controllers`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/routing-controllers). The decorators themselves do not do much. All they do is to store the arguments and some internal values into a global data structure. They represent only about 10% of the package code. The magic happens in the other 90%.

Answer (score -2):

I've just build a small npm package right for this, take a look. Its currently in BETA, but works fine: https://github.com/sannnekk/express-controller-decorator

Just look at the code in it, its pretty straightforward.

### Quick intro:

Class decorator is just a function taking as an argument a reference to the class. Method decorators work the same, but they can accept 2 more arguments: key (name of the function, you can use that later it invoke it) and descriptor (you don't need it for this task).

```js
function ClassDecorator(className) {
  // ... your code
}

function MethodDecorator(className, key, descriptor) {
  // ... your code
}

// use:

@ClassDecorator
class Foo {
  @MethodDecorator
  bar() {
    // ... your code
  }
}
```

Tipp: to be able to add parameters to your decorator just make them return a functon:

```js
function ClassDecorator(yourParam1, ...) {
  return function (className) {
    // ... your code
  }
}

function MethodDecorator(yourParam1, ...) {
  return function (className, key, descriptor) {
    // ... your code
  }
}

// use:

@ClassDecorator('blablalba')
class Foo {
  @MethodDecorator(123)
  bar() {
    // ... your code
  }
}
```

To register your class as a controller and methods as routes, just add some fields for this to the object prototype with the information about available methods and routes. Take a look at my implementation, if you need an example of all of this working